# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Lenovo Ideapad S405

Tags: uefi, battery, lenovo, ideapad

I installed Ubuntu on an S405 ideapad after disabling UEFI boot and enabling legacy support.

The most important problem is that while i get about 3-4  hours battery backup on windows, Ubuntu tells me immediately after unplugging from the power supply that there is something wrong with the battery and puts the laptop in hibernate mode. It does not allow me to disable this.

In addition, the S405 has a weird fn key that has to be pressed along with the function keys to make the function keys work, otherwise just pressing the function keys will run some functions like muting/increasin or decreasing volume/brightness etc. There is supposed to be an option in the bios to change this, according to the documentation, but its not there in my laptop. Is there anyway in Ubuntu that i can change these mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the function key, disable hot key in bios.

> Setting hotkey mode
>
> By default, the hotkey functions are accessible by pressing the
>   appropriate hotkey. However, you can disable the hotkey mode in the
>   BIOS setup utility.
>
> To disable the hotkey mode:
>
> 1. Restart the computer. When the Lenovo logo appears, immediately
>      press `Fn + F2` to enter the BIOS setup utility.
> 2. In the BIOS setup utility, open the Configuration menu, and change
>      the setting of HotKey Mode from Enabled to Disabled.
> 3. Exit Saving Changes.
>
> Note:When hotkey mode is disabled, press the `Fn` key and the
>   appropriate hotkey to access the corresponding hotkey function. <sub>From Manual</sub>